# Is it true that: $f\notin o(g)$ implies $\exists c>0: f > cg$ infinitely often

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

My (attempt at a) proof is as follows:

$f\in o(g)$ means that $\forall c>0 \exists n_0 \forall n\geq n_0: f(n) \leq cg(n)$.

Now taking the complement we get: $\exists c>0 \forall n_0 \exists n\geq n_0: f(n) > cg(n)$.

Fixing some $c'$ satisfying the above and $n_0=0$ we get some $n_1 \geq 0$ where $f(n_1) > cg(n_1)$. We can now repeat this process by choosing a 'new' $n_0=n_1 + 1$ yielding some $n_2 \geq n_1 + 1$ where $f(n_2) > cg(n_2)$. This process can now be repeated infinitely often which concludes the proof.

I would appreciate it if people would take a look and see if I have made a mistake. Note that I don't conclude $f\in o(g)$ implies $f = \Omega(g)$ (even though it in many ways similar).

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, this question fits perfectly here.

Comment: Negation is, of course, correct - in other words it can be say, that exists some subsequence of natural numbers $\left( n_k \right)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ for which $f(n_k)>cg(n_k)$.